# как установить Xamarin Studio c набором для IOS и Android?

Tags: xamarin

Здравствуйте, хочу пересесть на среду разработки Xamarin(для разработки IOS, Android аппов).Подскажите как установить весь набор Xamarin без использования Visual Studio, т.е. хочу пользоваться Xamarin Studio-и установить туда пакеты для IOS и Android.Сейчас в Xamarin Studio при создании нового проекта нет выбора Ios, Android.

Answer (score 1):

Плохие новости для Вас.
 Xamarin сейчас полноценная часть VS.

Если используете Windows, ставьте VS 2017 и выбирайте Xamarin как опцию при установке.

Если используете Mac OS ставьте Visual Studio для Mac(при установке надо указать, что вы хотите для андройда SDK так же установить), так как это фактическое продолжение Xamarin Studio.

Либо ставьте Rider
https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/

Comment: А можно только в VS 2017?2013 не подходит?

Comment: он там ставился, как плагин. Сначала VS потом плагин. 
Можно узнать, в чем проблема поставить 2017?